# Save and Share application settings between server and webclient

Tags: node.js, angular, configuration

I'm writing an application with NodeJs and a web frontend hopefully with angular. So my application needs some settings which should be accessible by the server and the client.

By settings I mean some Dates, and other values. 
For example I want to hide a registration site after a specific date and want the api to reject any requests after this date.
Because this Date change from year to year I want to configure this in my application. So I don't need to deploy this each year again.

But I have no idea which is the best practice to implement this.

Hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in advance
Dominic

Comment: what do u mean by settings?

Comment: I updated my question